# limit the result using cts:collection-match in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have 2 collections in collections.

- /test/1

This has 10 documents with id

```
test1_1
test1_2
.....
test1_10
```

- /test/2

This has 20 documents with id as follows

```
test2_1
test2_2
.....
test2_20
```

Query:

```
let $result := cts:collection-match("/test/*")
let $id :=(
  fn:distinct-values(
    for $doc in fn:collection(result)
    order by $doc//timestamp descending
    return $doc//timestamp/text()
  )[1 to 5]
)
return $id
```

I want to return the **top 5 documents from each collection** descending order of timestamp but it returns only 5 documents not 10 i.e. top 5 from each collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `$result` is a sequence of greater than one item, writing `for $doc in fn:collection($result)` aggregates all of the documents from multiple collections into a single sequence. You need to iterate over collections first, then iterate over the values in each collection, ordered and limited.

```
let $collections := cts:collection-match("/test/*")
let $id :=         
    for $collection in $collections
    return 
      fn:distinct-values(
        for $doc in fn:collection($collection)
        order by $doc//timestamp descending
           return $doc//timestamp/string()
      )[1 to 5]
return $id
```

Comment: works but is there any other way for avoid using 2 for in query.

Comment: @coder25 Not in any way that would matter substantively. You need the inner `for` to use `order by, and to get a separate result set for each collection, you need to execute that query once for each.

Comment: @coder25 The only alternative I can think of is to create a range index on `timestamp` and use `cts:search` with the `cts:index-order` option (with a reference to the `timestamp` index). That would reduce the inner `for` loop into a functional call to `cts:search`; however, under the hood, it is still iterating.

Comment: I tried using index order but the result doesnot sort in descending order

Comment: @coder25 Ascending is the default; you have to specify descending using an option. See the documentation: https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order

Comment: ```let $distinctId :=         
    for $id in $Ids
    return 
      fn:distinct-values(
       let $doc:=(cts:search(
            collection(),
            cts:collection-query($id),
            cts:index-order(
             cts:element-attribute-reference(
               fn:QName("http://www.test.com","timestamp"),fn:QName("","value"),
               "type=dateTime"
                ),
               "descending"
            )
           )
       )return $doc//timestamp//@value/text()
      )[1 to 3]

return $distinctId```

Comment: I specified descending but still it comes in wrong order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168944/discussion-between-coder25-and-wst).