# Is there any way to limit the number of documents returned by a structured query?

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic, marklogic-10

I'm using the NiFi QueryMarkLogic processor to fetch a collection with 600,000 documents and getting a cryptic error. I'm using a structured cts:collection-query. My hunch is that the amount of data is just too large, so I'd like to fetch less than the full set of documents. In Query Console I could just do something like `fn:subsequence(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:collection-query("My Collection")), 1, 1000)`, but I can't find any way to do the equivalent in a structured query or even a combined query.

Edit: The specific error I'm getting is:

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: 
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: 
StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=0461...] transfer relationship not specified. 
This FlowFile was created in this session and was not transferred to any Relationship 
via ProcessSession.transfer()
```

Comment: "getting a cryptic error"  Is it so cryptic that you cannot share this error message ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [limit the result using cts:collection-match in marklogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821007/limit-the-result-using-ctscollection-match-in-marklogic)

Comment: Thanks, Luuk, but the QueryMarkLogic processor doesn't take arbitrary XQuery. I'm sending a structured query at the moment.

Comment: What version of the connector are you using? That is almost certainly a bug, if a FlowFile was created and not transferred anywhere. You should definitely be able to use QueryMarkLogic here and not have any issue with only 600k docs being returned. But if it's a bug, please file an issue at marklogic/nifi in GitHub.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.16 fixed the problem. I didn't even realize the connectors were on GitHub until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that processor does not do what you want, you can always fall back to the `ExecuteScriptMarkLogic` processor.

Please note that over recent times, all of the MarkLogic NiFI processors were re-worked and standardized. So if you are using an old version, I suggest that you upgrade.

Related to what you are trying to do, I have done something similar in the past:

1. Use ExecuteScriptMarkLogic to segment my data into collection - returning the collection names.
2. Pass those names individually to the queryMarkLogicProcessor.

However, much of the NiFI code for Apache handles batches nicely internally, so I'd check the newest docs closely first.